# Splunk: Referencing field transformations within field transformations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku, nginx, splunk

I'm using [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) to receive my [Heroku logs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#syslog_drains) over TCP.  Heroku formats these logs like this:

```
[timestamp] [host] [source] [process] - - [message]
```

For the nginx process, logs come out like this:

```
[timestamp] [host] heroku nginx - - [nginx's output]
```

I'd like to process these logs using Splunk's default access-extractions field transformtion.  I had a look at some of the other built in transformations that reference other transformations and tried this as the regex for my new transformation:

```
(?i) heroku nginx \- \- [[access-extractions]]
```

However, when I click "Save" I get:

> Encountered the following error while trying to save: 
>   In handler 'transforms-extract': 
>   Regex: range out of order in character class

What's the syntax to reference other field transformations from within a field transformation?  Is this the best way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I upgraded to v4.3.1 and the regex works now.